# MDX Getcurrent PricelogID of Product Dimemsion

Tags: mdx

I have tables:

```
Table Products ( ProductID , ProductName,..) --Dimemsion
Table PriceLog (PriceLogID, Price, ApplyDate,...) Log the price of product at the event time. - Dimemsion
Table Sale (SaleID, ProductID, PriceLogID,...) --Measure
```

Now I want to wirte a MDX query for report like this:

```
ProductID, ProductName, PriceLogID, CountProductSold
1          Tivi       ,10          ,20
1          Tivi       ,11          ,23
2          Phone      ,10          ,55
2          Phone      ,12          ,10
```

But my problem is get PriceLogID and CountProductSold, the system give me a OutOffMemory error because I have over 10000 PriceLogID

This is my query

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[COUNTProductSold] AS 
    Count(Exists([Measures].[Sale],[Products].[ProductID].[ProductID])) 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[COUNTProductSold] ON COLUMNS
 ,
    [Products].[ProductID].[ProductID]*
    [Products].[ProductID].[Product Name]*
    [PriceLog].[PriceLogID].[PriceLogID] ON ROWS
FROM [my cube];
```

Error:

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

Comment: please add the `mdx` script that is causing the error.

Comment: I just add mdx script,

Answer (score 0):

Does the below work for you?

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[COUNTProductSold] AS 
    Count(
         NonEmpty
              (
              [Products].[ProductID].[ProductID], 
              [Measures].[Sale]
              )
         ) 
SELECT 
    [Measures].[COUNTProductSold] ON COLUMNS,        
    [Products].[ProductID].[ProductID]* [Products].[ProductID].[Product Name]* [PriceLog].[PriceLogID].[PriceLogID] ON ROWS
FROM [my cube];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, because  the measure priceLog have over 10000 record, when counting, the mdx will calculated 10000times for each productID. 
The solution is using NonEmpty function with subquery.

Comment: Share the solution too for the benefit of others.